# How to make a map pointer using reflect?

Tags: reflection, go

I need to pass a pointer to a map to another function using the reflect package. Think of encoding/json.Unmarshal which accepts only pointers. Below is some code of what I need to do using reflection:

```
  myTyp := &MyType{}
  json.Unmarshal(jsonPayload1, myTyp)
  m := make(map[string]*MyType)
  m["someKey"] = myTyp
  // Dump it again to Unmarshal. It will overwrite it only if 
  // there is a `someKey` key.
  x := json.Unmarshal(jsonPayload2, &m)
```

So far I have the following:

```
  ....
  m := reflect.MakeMap(reflect.MapOf(reflect.TypeOf(""), reflect.TypeOf(typ))
  x := json.Unmarshal(jsonPayload2, m.Interface())
```

The issue with this code is that it's making a map of map[string]MyType but there is no way I can create a pointer for it. If I try to make the pointer [2] directly it panics with `reflect.MakeMap of non-map type`.

**Why the map must be allocated:**

I need the map allocated so that I can set myTyp on a specific key. myTyp is decoded using multiple decoding sources so I don't know what fields were decoded with each source but I know that Unmarshal overwrites only keys that match the json content/keys so it's safe to use the same variable to multiple Unmarshal functions.

[2] `reflect.MakeMap(reflect.PtrTo(reflect.MapOf(reflect.TypeOf("")),  reflect.TypeOf(typ))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a function like `json.Unamrshal`, you don't need the map, you only need the correct type pointer, which you can make with `reflect.New`. The json package will allocate the map as needed.

```
m := reflect.New(reflect.MapOf(reflect.TypeOf(""), reflect.TypeOf(typ)))
```

If you need to allocate the map, use the Set method to assign it to the pointer.

http://play.golang.org/p/hnOhh8242i

```
mapType := reflect.MapOf(reflect.TypeOf(""), reflect.TypeOf(typ))

ptr := reflect.New(mapType)
ptr.Elem().Set(reflect.MakeMap(mapType))
```

Comment: The issue is that I can't assign to the map created(as it's not allocated). I will edit the question to elaborate why this is an issue.

Comment: I've updated the question. Long story short is that I need the map allocated unless I'm willing to implement a diff function and additional copies after each Unmarshal

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat: OK, added an example of setting the pointer value to an allocated map.