# golang lost in the reflection

Tags: go, reflection

I am traing  to abstract a rest API with go lang but i totally stuck in the reflection part.

```
    log.Printf("handleIndex resourceType = %v", res.resourceType)

slice := reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.SliceOf(res.resourceType), 0, 0)
err := res.api.DB.Select(&slice, "SELECT * FROM domains")
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("SQL Error %s", err)
}
fmt.Printf("\n=================================== \n%#v \n=================================== ", slice)
```

resourceType is a reflect.Type of the model

res.api.DB is sqlx.DB

Output of the code is :

handleIndex resourceType = main.Domain

## SQL Error  expected slice but got struct

## []main.Domain{}

so basically even i make a slice of reflect.Type i got a struct
What i am missing ?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33179876/how-to-make-a-map-pointer-using-reflect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing a pointer to a `reflect.Value` into your `Select` call. A `reflect.Value` is a struct, which is why you're receiving this error.

Instead, create a new pointer of the type you want using [`reflect.New`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#New)

```
slice := reflect.New(reflect.SliceOf(res.resourceType))
err := res.api.DB.Select(slice.Interface(), "SELECT * FROM domains")
```